# How do I view a different flipper in Layout view of an xml?

Tags: android, xml, layout, viewflipper

Hey all - I am using a flipper in my main xml file to view multiple layouts in my app.

For instance, if something = 1, the user is shown one version of the flipper, where if something = 2 the user sees a different version.

Is there a way I can view the layout of the xml file for the other flippers I have rather than the main one?  Ie, is there a way to switch views of each state of the flipper in eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest including all flippers in your xml file. Use `android:visibility="gone"` for the flippers that won't show by default, or all of them. Then in your code you can toggle them back on with `flipper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. The others should `View.GONE`.

For a cleaner XML file *(especially if you have a lot of flippers)*, you can use `<include>` statements to each flipper source.

Comment: All the flippers are included, I am just asking if it is possible to view and manipulate different flippers in Layout view (so I can drag and drop stuff) rather than just edit flippers in code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't understand what you mean by "drag and drop stuff". Are you looking to drag objects from one flipper view into another flipper view?